# How to write a HTTP Request in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I just find `Meteor.methods` and `Meteor.call` in Meteor API, but I want write a `post` or `get` methods given to another App invoke. what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the meteor package `http`.

Install it by running `meteor add http`

[Here is a link to the docs which has example calls and lists all the arguments you can pass the http call](https://docs.meteor.com/api/http.html)

AN example of a call from the docs:

```
const result = HTTP.call('GET', 'http://api.twitter.com/xyz', {
    params: { user: userId }
});
```

Comment: Maybe my description made you confused, I wanna write a methods, and another client invoke this methods, I don't want invoke mothods. 

Forgive my poor English, sad...

Answer (score 0):

Look like you want to receive HTTP get and post requests. Am I right?
If yes, look at this package: [restivus](https://github.com/kahmali/meteor-restivus)

Comment: Yeah! I wanna write a interface for create REST API, Thanks!